# Using Apache Commons CLI to detect absence of command line arguments/options

Tags: java, apache-commons-cli

I am currently using the library `Apache Commons CLI 1.3.1` to parse command line arguments and control the flow of execution in an executable jar.  So far everything has been pretty straightforward and the [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-release/index.html) and [example usage](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html) pages have been relatively thorough and helpful.

However, I am still unclear about how to use this library to detect the absence of any arguments or options.  I would like to detect this condition and then print a usage/help statement.  I have gotten around this by simply checking the length of the argument array, but I would like to know if the library has a way of detecting this condition without checking for the presence of every option.

Here is my code with the work-around left in:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
       // create Options object
       Options options = new Options();

       // add t option
       options.addOption("t", false, "display current time");
       options.addOption("help", false, "print this message");

       CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
       CommandLine cmd = parser.parse(options, args);

       if(cmd.hasOption("t")) {
           log.debug("Received option t");
           // Do something
       }

       if (args.length <= 0 || cmd.hasOption("help"))
       {
           // automatically generate the help statement
           HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
           formatter.printHelp( "java -jar Client.jar <option> <arguments>", options);
       }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`getArgList`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/cli/CommandLine.html#getArgList--) or the [`getArgs`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/cli/CommandLine.html#getArgs--) method. From the documentation:

> Retrieve any left-over non-recognized options and arguments

So instead of this:

> ```
>    if (args.length <= 0 || cmd.hasOption("help"))
> ```

Use like this:

```
   if (cmd.getArgs().length == 0 || cmd.hasOption("help"))
```

Comment: Beautiful.  I misunderstood the documentation.  I had thought this was an argument list submitted for a particular option.  Thank you.  BTW it should be `cmd.getArgs().length`

Comment: But it might be important to note that this will not work if your program is expecting a switch without arguments.  For example, if I use that method then the help will print even when the command is `client.jar -t`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the correction! If your program should not have excess arguments, then of course you should change the condition, and in fact raise an error in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Note that cmd.getArgs().length do not count switches (-xxxx) on the command line - only args not starting with dash